# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy - Nuxt.js + GAE

Tags: vue.js, seo, cache, rendimiento, google-app-engine

Esto es lo que obtengo de **Lighthouse**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el Cache TTL en una aplicación **Nuxt.js** SSR? he encontrado respuestas pero nada relacionado con Nuxt.js....

**IMPORTANTE**: Desplegado en Google App Engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta específica para una aplicación GAE, es el parámetro `handlers.expiration` en el archivo `app.yaml`:

```yaml
handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    expiration: 4d 5h
    secure: always
```

O si lo que quieres es configurarlo globalmente, configura el parámetro `default_expiration` a nivel raíz:

```yaml
default_expiration: 4d 5h
```

Permite `d` (días), `h` (horas), `m` (minutos) and `s` (segundos). Aquí la documentación [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element)